# iOS 13 : Allow Once Location permission with WiFi SSID result in error : [ ] nehelper sent invalid result code [1] for Wi-Fi information request

Tags: swift, location, wifi, ios13

I have been using WiFi Information in my app. I have been using this functionality perfectly till now but since iOS 13 and introduction of new location permission "Allow Once" it throws me this error: **[ ] nehelper sent invalid result code [1] for Wi-Fi information request.** This error comes when I try to switch to the WiFi Setting page to connect to WiFi SSID for **the second time** in my app.

**Allow Once Permission:**

It gives provisional authorization which is similar to 'When in Use' permission but active for only a single session. So, If a user chooses the allow once permission option, your app can access their current location until your app is moved to the background and becomes inactive. If your app becomes active again, you have to ask for location permission again.

*Below is my code to get location permission:*

```
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

In my case, I select **Allow once** permission then goes to the background twice to select the WiFi access point 2 times in total. It works for the first time, however, in 2nd time it does not give me connected WiFi SSID information and instead it gives me this error: ***[ ] nehelper sent invalid result code [1] for Wi-Fi information request.*** How can I have connected WiFi SSID all the time in 'Allow Once' location permission? As per the new changes in iOS 13 as below:

> WiFi configuration is using CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo which returns the
>   current network information for a given network interface. So this
>   dictionary is containing our current network Info mainly SSID of wifi
>   network.
>
> The requesting app must meet the following requirements:
>
> The app uses Core Location and has the user’s authorization to use
>   location information.
>
> An app that fails to meet the above requirements receives the
>   following return value:
>
> An app linked against iOS 12 or earlier receives a dictionary with
>   pseudo-values. In this case, the SSID is Wi-Fi (or WLAN in the China
>   region), and the BSSID is 00:00:00:00:00:00.
>
> An app linked against* iOS 13* or later receives NULL.
>
> *If you don't meet the above conditions CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo will always return nil in iOS 13.*
>
> Reference:
>   [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1614126-cncopycurrentnetworkinfo][1]

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: @Magnas I added details. Thanks